# Nuxt JS | Where/how to set global data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Today I started playing with NuxtJS and was wondering what the best way to set/retrieve global data would be?

For example a phone number that gets repeated throughout a site, should be managed from a single location.

Would AsyncData be the way to go? Is that overkill?

In Vue.js you'd have global data attached to the main Vue instance. What is the Nuxt equivalent of this (if there is one).

Comment: Wouldn't state management like VueX a better approach in general for global data? Attaching data to the vue instance for the sake of data storage doesn't seem like a very flexible approach. Also vuex is directly supported by nuxt.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at **[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)**, the vue state management pattern and library.

It serves as a centralized store for all the components in a vue application.

Comment: Thanks Sammy. I figured there'd be a more elegant solution somewhere, just needed a point in the right direction.